# Which Jquery Plugin is Being used in This Site?

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

Does anyone know which plugin is being used in this page when you scroll down and the photo is put together?

http://www.madeo.academy/en/

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why not see for yourself? Use them developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but I will answer your questions by telling you the steps to see it for your self.

1. Launch Chrome browser
2. Enter http://www.madeo.academy/en/ in the address bar
3. Press F12
4. Click on Sources tab
5. Expand the Script folder
6. Expand the plugin folder

Now you know which plugins, you can do some google search on how to implement them in your projects. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I didn't know this feature :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Hope you find the developer tool as useful as I do.